# Make a dynamic text object

Tags: text-object

How to make text object so the 'text' is updated automatically to show/display its current location. For example : the text showing the z position that will update automatically when i move the object up or down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using Animation Nodes ([link to the site here](https://animation-nodes.com/)):

[image]

Get the text as object transform input in order to have its coordinates.

Convert the location to text.

Use it as text object output.

Comment: fantastic!!!!!!

Comment: awesome , thanksl