# Can you use an object's dimension and put it in text, such that if the dimension changes, the text changes too?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, text-object

For example, I want to use the Z dimension of the cylinder and put the value in the text.
[image: Picture]
I tried to do so using Python, but I don't know how to use it in blender.

Comment: With animation nodes - yes. Or Sverchok

Comment: I *think* it's impossible to drive the actual string of a text object. You can use AN though. see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/204078/86891 or use the depsgraph update handler similar to https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/blender+change+text+during+animation

Comment: >Thanks a lot @Gorgious , I used the example given in the link, it works perfectly after using Separate vectors and taking the Z vector into the round number node. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by this script:

```
import bpy

def update_driver():
        bpy.data.objects['Text'].data.body = "z = %f" %bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location.z
        return 1
    
bpy.app.driver_namespace["update_driver"] = update_driver
```

So your text-object should be "Text" or adapt the name in the script.
Your Object should be called 'Cube' or adapt the name in the script.

1. add a custom property to your cube/object.
2. Add driver:

[image]

3. run script

whenever a frame is rendered, the text will update. This does NOT work in the viewport.